# How to access data when a viewModel depends on several models

Tags: c#, mvvm, repository-pattern

I'm a novice trying to wrap my head around MVVM. I'm trying to build something and have not found an answer on how to deal with this:

I have several models/entities, some of which have logical connections and I am wondering where/when to bring it all together nicely.

Assume we have a PersonModel:

```
public class PersonModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And a ClubModel:

```
public class ClubModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And we have `MembershipModel` (a Person can have several Club memberships):

```
public class MembershipModel 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PersonId { get; set; }
    public ClubId { get; set; }
}
```

All these models are stored somewhere, and the models are persisted "as in" in that data storage.

Assume we have separate repositories in place for each of these models that supplies the standard CRUD operations.

Now I want to create a view model to manage all Persons, e.g. renaming, adding memberships, etc. -> `PersonMangementViewModel`.

In order to nicely bind a Person with all its properties and memberships, I would also create a PersonView(?)Model that can be used in the PersonManagementViewModel. It could contain e.g. view relevant properties and also the memberships:

```
public class PersonViewModel : PersonModel 
{
    public Color BkgnColor { get return SomeLogic(); }
    public IEnumerable<MembershipModel> { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

My question here is, how would I smartly go about getting the Membership info into the PersionViewModel? I could of course create an instance of the MemberShipRepo directly in the PersionViewModel but that seems not nice, especially if you have a lot of Persons. I could also create all repositories in the PersonManagementViewModel and then pass references into the PersonViewModel.

Or does it make more sense to create another layer (e.g. "service" layer) that returns primarily the PersonViewModel, therefore uses the individual repositories and is called from the PersonManagementViewModel (thus removing the burden from it and allowing for re-use of the service elsewhere)?

Happy to have pointed out conceptional mistakes or some further reading.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating separate model for each table I guess. Does not matter, but your models are fragmented. You can consider putting related data together using Aggregate Root and Repository per Aggregate root instead of per model. This concept is discussed under DDD. But as you said you are new to MVVM, there is already lot much to learn. Involving DDD at this stage will only complicate the things.

If you decide to keep the things as is, best and quick thing I can guess is what you are doing now. Get instance of model from data store in View Model (or whatever your location) and map somehow. Tools like Automapper are good but they does not fit each situation. Do not hesitate to map by hand if needed. You can also use mix approach (Automapper + map by hand) to simplify the things.

About service layer, sure... why not. Totally depends on you. If used, this layer typically contain your business logic, mapping, formatting of data, validations etc. Again, each of that thing is up to you.

My suggestions:

- **Focus on your business objectives first.**
- Design patterns are good and helpful. Those are extract of many exceptionally capable developers to solve specific problem. Do use them. But, do not unnecessarily stick to it. Read above suggestion. In short, avoid over-engineering. Design patterns are created to solve specific problem. If you do not have that problem, then do not mess-up your code with unnecessary pattern.
- Read about Aggregate Root, DDD, Repository etc.
- Try your best to avoid Generic Repository.